# 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable

Tags: model, token, tokenize, bert-language-model

I've tried to Instantiate tokenizer following this sentence:

tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module(bert_path=BERT_PATH)

I tried fixed it with some of that other topic recommendations

But the code failure, please see the screenshot below:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncqss.png)

Detail code:

Def moment:

def create_tokenizer_from_hub_module(bert_path):
"""Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
bert_module =  tf_hub.load(bert_path)
tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run(
[
tokenization_info["vocab_file"],
tokenization_info["do_lower_case"],
]
)

```
return FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)
```

Instance moment:

tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module(bert_path=BERT_PATH)